# Using render_template in Flask, how to split a string into multiple lines?

Tags: python, string, api, flask

So, I'm messing around with the star wars swapi API, and rendering my api search onto an html file as a string, however I cannot seem to separate the titles in the string by line:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import requests
import json
import swapi

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    url = "https://swapi.co/api/"
    star_wars_api = requests.get(url)

    result = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        films = requests.get(star_wars_api.json()['films'])
        if films.status_code == 200:
            if request.form['search'] == "films":
                film_json = films.json()

                for film in film_json['results']:
                    result += str(film['title'])

                return render_template('index.html', results=result)
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the HTML file:

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}

{% block head %} {% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<form action="/" method="POST">
    <label for="search">Search:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>

<p> {{ results }}</p>

{% endblock %}
```

Here is the output: (on the `index.html` page)

"A New HopeAttack of the ClonesThe Phantom MenaceRevenge of the SithReturn of the JediThe Empire Strikes BackThe Force Awakens" (without the quotes)

Comment: I'll remove the redundant quotes to ease confusion, however the remove doesn't change the output whatsoever.

Comment: what do you have in `results`? If single line then you can't split it. If you have many lines then replace `'\n` with `<br>`, or use `<pre></pre>` instead of `<p></p>`

Comment: Frankly you should send titles as list, not string and use `{% for %}` in template to display eveery title in separate `<p>` or add `<br>` to every title.

Answer (score 2):

In HTML you have to use `<br>` instead of `\n` to put text in new line.

You should get titles as list and then use `"<br>".join(titles)`

```
titles = []

for film in film_json['results']:
    titles.append( film['title'] )

result = "<br>".join(titles)

return render_template('index.html', results=result)
```

Or you should send list with titles to template

```
result = []

for film in film_json['results']:
    result.append( film['title'] )

return render_template('index.html', results=result)
```

and use `{% for %}` loop in template

```
<p>
{% for title in results %} 
{{ title }}<br>
{% endfor %}
</p>
```

---

Eventually you should add `'\n'` to every title

```
for film in film_json['results']:
    result += film['title'] + "\n"

return render_template('index.html', results=result)
```

and use `<pre>` instead `<p>` and it will respect `"\n"` (but it will use monospace font because it was created to display code - like this code in answer)

```
<pre>{{ result }}</pre>
```

Comment: That was it! I tried to figure out how to send each title into a list but I'm new to all of this and totally forgot that I could append each one, also the jinja for loop.